# Running Powershell script from SSIS with OnTap cmdlets throws error, but not when run from PS Cmd Line?

Tags: powershell, ssis

We are trying to run a Poweshell Script that uses the OnTap PS Modules, from SSIS, when we do, an error is issued:

Error: The term 'Connect-NaController' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

But when we run the same script from the Powershell Command Line, then the script runs just fine. So I think the scripts are fine.

So I'm wondering if the security context is different or we have to do something more explicitly in our call from SSIS?

When we call the script from SSIS we use: -ExecutionPolicy ByPass

Thanks!

Comment: Please supply command you use to run the script from SSIS. Does the script ìmport the module ?

Comment: This smells suspiciously like a permissions or pathing issue. When you run the package yourself does the script work or is this an "only when run via agent" it fails? Also, the referenced PS module is the [NetApp DataONTAP](http://powertap.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This is the cmd line used in SSIS:  -ExecutionPolicy ByPass ./cleanup_flexclone -filer nas101 -ServerName query101 -FolderName Cube_Data.   running it in PS no error. SSIS = error.

Comment: The script does not import the module because it works fine from PS Command Line.

Answer (score 1):

In SSIS i had to set the FULL PATH of the script instead of ./scriptfile